Do parallel SELECTs make a transaction?
While running under READ COMMITTED (the pessimistic type, not RCSI), I've just seen an UPDATE's IX lock deadlock with a SELECT's shared lock on the PAGE-level. The SELECT ran with a parallel execution plan. Neither explicitly used a transaction. I understand that UPDATEs implicitly create transactions. Does this suggest that parallel SELECTs also create implicit transactions? Is this not true of non-parallel SELECTs?
I'm finding this rather confusing, because none of the textbook examples of deadlocks show two transaction-less queries deadlocking.

it's not the transaction
If you play Lock Compatibility Battleship™️, you'll find that Shared locks can't sink your destroyer very easily, but Object-Level Shared Locks are a different sort of torpedo. You won't even have time for one ping only.

In most cases, S locks are taken and released very quickly, but there are certain things that will prolong those locks. I've blogged about those in relation to Key Lookups with Prefetching:

When Read Queries Block Write Queries In SQL Server
Why Read Queries Deadlock With Write Queries In SQL Server

The first thing that I would look at is the query plan for the parallel select query and see if there are any lookups with the prefetch attribute. In some cases, fixing the lookup with additional index columns is easy enough. In other cases, you may need to hint a different index.
If the lookup was chosen based on poor cardinality estimates, or because of parameter sniffing, your may decide on a different path to solve the problem.
On the off chance that this is not the case, please provide the query plans for the select, and for the modification query, along with any useful contextual information, like table and index definitions, triggers, indexed views, etc.

Yes the SELECT will run in a transaction (and create one if needed as either you are running in auto commit mode or you are running with implicit transactions on and the SELECT isn't the exception mentioned here). This applies equally to serial or parallel execution plans.
If you start off a SELECT from a large table in auto commit mode in one window and go to another and run
SELECT request_mode, request_type,request_status, request_owner_id, request_owner_type
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks
WHERE request_session_id = <id_from_original_session> AND request_owner_type = 'TRANSACTION'

whilst the original SELECT is still running then you should see that the lock(s) held by the SELECT are allocated to a transaction and if you repeat the experiment and add CURRENT_TRANSACTION_ID() to the SELECT list against the large table you will see that the value returned by that matches the request_owner_id returned by the sys.dm_tran_locks query.
These auto commit SELECT transactions don't seem to show up in sys.dm_tran_session_transactions though as shown by the below (where dm_tran_current_transaction happily reports details of a transaction not shown in the other DMV).
SELECT *,
       SessionTransactionCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.dm_tran_session_transactions WHERE session_id = @@SPID)
FROM sys.dm_tran_current_transaction 

Nor do they fire off any transaction related extended events as far as I could see so they seem like a very lightweight variant on the theme.
